# System.FormatException when adding User-Agent with colon

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a http request like this one https://tools.keycdn.com/geo.json?host=google.com in C#. For this, according to the https://tools.keycdn.com/geo?host=google.com, I have to add user agent like this

```
User-Agent: keycdn-tools:https://myownsite.com
```

I am doing the request with this code:

```
HttpClient? client = new HttpClient();

// Add correct user agent.
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://tools.keycdn.com/geo.json?host=" + textBoxDomain.Text);
var useragentValue = new ProductInfoHeaderValue("keycdn-tools:https://myownsite.com");
request.Headers.UserAgent.Add(useragentValue);

var result = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

But I get the System.FormatException when adding the user agent.

[image]

How can I resolve this problem?

**Edit**

I tried to solve the problem by adding DefaultRequestHeaders directly to client object, but I got the same error message

[image]

Then I tried to add the header to the request, but there I got also the same error message

[image]

Comment: Colons aren’t valid in a ProductInfoHeaderValue

Answer (score 2):

.NET's `ProductInfoHeaderValue` helper class is enforcing syntax restrictions that the [HTTP specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-4.2) doesn't require for `User-Agent` because the purpose of this class is to create a value that follows the RFC's [specification for product tokens](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-3.8).

You can instead add `User-Agent` directly to the `Headers` collection:

```
request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "keycdn-tools:https://myownsite.com");
```

If you wish to set the same user agent for every request made by that `request` instance:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "my-user-agent-name");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  but unfortunately it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: How so? Do you get another error? Do you not get the expected reqponse from your request?